# JavaScript not reading textbox value

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a simple login page where I accept values and print them back. I have written a function in javascript to store input values from text box. I have added two print statements to just check till where my program works. Here is my script.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Home| Login</title>
</head>


<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            document.write("Reached Point 1");
            document.write(document.getElementById("username").value);
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            document.write("Reached Point 2");
        }
    </script>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="login-block">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type="text" value="" id="username" />
        <input type="text" value="" id="password" />
        <button onclick="init()">Submit</button>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`Reached Point 1` is getting printed on clicking the button but the username and `Reached Point 2` are not getting printed.

Comment: Hi there. Maybe document.write is not the best way to go about it. Try console.log("reached point 1") instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `document.write` once the document has completed loading. If you do, the browser will open a new document that replaces the current. And as the document is replace there won't be any functions and HTML Elements and anything. Instead use `innerHTML` to put HTML code inside an element.

```js
        function init() {
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML += "Reached Point 1";
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML +=  document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML += "Reached Point 2";
        }
```

```html
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="login-block">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type="text" value="" id="username" />
        <input type="text" value="" id="password" />
        <button onclick="init()">Submit</button>
        <p id="description"></p>
    </div>
```